# Invalid trailer in pdf java itext 5.4.3

Tags: itext

My requirement is to add the time stamp in the bottom of the PDF. I'm using itext 5.4.3 version to edit the PDF and able to add the time-stamp successfully. But the process is throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception for some PDF.. Attaching the exception stack trace below.

```
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.createInfoId(PdfEncryption.java:558)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:383)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:337)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:206)
```

I did the analysis and found this issue is happening due to bad trailer exist in pdf,itext is expecting 16 bit trailer data whereas my pdf is having only 4 bit or some times 10 bit. Attaching the trailer information below.

**Valid Trailer:**
/ID AA8280F47FC1BF4DCD5C88E6A493092D

**Invalid Trailer**:
/ID B2DE387A

We have asked vendor to re-scan the PDF again but looks like most of the PDF is having the similar trailer. Is there anyway to edit the PDF using itext which is having invalid trailer? Please help.

Any updated version will fix the issue?

Comment: You are either using the AGPL version of iText (in which case you are probably not using iText in a commercial environment) or you have a commercial license for your use of iText. This is typically a question you should post to paid support at iText Software if you have a commercial license. If you don't have a commercial license, you should fix this yourself in the source code and post the fix back along with all the rest of your code.

Comment: The latest version is 5.5.7, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reproducible with 5.4.3, but not with the current version, 5.5.7.

This is probably the commit that fixed it: [e28f688033](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/e28f688033649d980bdd3a1a3d6c344d4ea63ff5)
(This fix seems to be a bit overkill, because it's creating new IDs whenever the existing one aren't 16 bytes, which isn't a requirement.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is it possible to create the document id before closing the stamper?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Seeing that the question about the invalid trailer is answered, it's better to create a new question about changing/creating documents ids.

Comment: I tried the same to create the document id before closing the stamper but no luck. Can you please help me on this?